How to run a customized rule on a mail folder in Outlook?
I use Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO, Version 2402, Build 16.0.17328.20282, 64-bit
(Microsoft 365 apps for Enterprise). It's the same app as this question: How to identify the location of a message in Outlook's search results?
I'd like to run a customized rule in a folder to e.g. delete all messages older than 6 months.
When I click on the folder -> Properties -> Policy -> Add or Remove Retention Policies, I am brought to the web version of Outlook, Mail Settings. From there there is no option to set up a retention policy or any customized rule that would do what I want.
This might depend on my corporate settings, but there should be a way anyway.
How to do so?

Setting retention policies is restricted by IT administrators.
In Outlook client setting rules, you can set to delete messages within a period of time.  Move>>Rules>>Create Rule...>> Advanced Options>> Received in a specific date span >> Delete it.



Are these rules applied only to incoming mail, or to all folders? Is there a way to set a rule only for the messages inside a specific folder?

This is for all mails. Applying to a specific folder is not supported in the rule. It is recommend that you contact your administrator to set up a retention policy.
